# Check if current page is the Blog Page

Tags: php, blog, blog-page

I'm new to WordPress. I am looking for a way to check if current page is the blog page in the code of the header file.

I've checked but I can't find a way. Help me, Pls.

Answer (score 67):

If by '**blog page**' you meant a *static page* set as *posts page* in the **Reading Settings**, then you could check it by doing this:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```

> When you use `is_home()` and `is_front_page()`, you have to use them in
>   **the right order** to avoid bugs and to test every user configuration.

*(Source: [**Conditional Tags - The Blog Page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Blog_Page))*

Or simply:

```
if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // blog page
}
```

Or more simply (I suppose):

```
if ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
}
```

Comment: One use case to use `if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() )`, at least in my opinion, is if you are distributing a theme that has different layout style for the **default homepage** and the **blog page**.

Comment: I'm finding is_front_page() will return true whether or not the blog archive or a page is selected. Need verification. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

Answer (score 30):

You can use the following in your themes functions.php file:

```
function is_blog () {
    return ( is_archive() || is_author() || is_category() || is_home() || is_single() || is_tag()) && 'post' == get_post_type();
}
```

And then put this in the file you are checking:

```
<?php if (is_blog()) { echo 'You are on a blog page'; } ?>
```

You can use Hooks in your functions.php file to hook the above, to make that appear on every page.

Comment: This is a great answer if you want to determine if you're on _a_ blog page,  but not neccessarily _the_ blog page (as in the blog home page). See @Giraldi's answer for that.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed is_blog() exists because is_page() exists. It didn't occur to me to consult the [official WordPress Conditional Tags Index](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Conditional_Tags_Index). I was able to effectively apply this solution using the Widget Logic plugin.

Answer (score 18):

If by 'blog page' you meant a static page set as posts page in the Reading:

```
global $wp_query;

if ( isset( $wp_query ) && (bool) $wp_query->is_posts_page ) {
    //static blog page
}
```

PS. This solution  also works on **template_redirect** action

Comment: Hi repinsa, welcome to WPSE :) Thanks for adding your answer. It's been voted down a bit, probably because it has a syntax error in the code (it's missing a semicolon after the `global $wp_query`) but also because it doesn't fully answer the question. It's a function, but the OP asked how to work this out in his header file - so it might need a little more explanation about what to put where. Again, welcome, glad to have you here!

Comment: That's actually the only good answer here, should have had more upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

To get the **blog index page**, I found that

```
if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // blog page
}
```

is not working for me, I had to use the get_option('page_for_posts') function to identify the Blog Page post_id, my answer is

```
if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ){  

    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id =  get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    }

    //blog page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use..

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>

Do stuff here

<?php } ?>
```

to check if it's a single blog post. Or...

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>

Do stuff here

<?php } ?>
```

to check if it's the blog homepage

Comment: Doesn't work if you've changed the blog page

Comment: This doesn't provide a correct answer to the OP.  This indicates you are on a single post, not "the blog page".

Answer (score 0):

I use this way

```
// Get body classes as array
$body_classes = get_body_class();
// Check if "blog" class exists in the array
if(in_array("blog", $body_classes)) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky method.

http://example.com/blog

Suppose if your blog page slug is **`blog`**, you can use this code.

```
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->query['pagename']=='blog'){
// this is blog page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HOMEPAGE

```
if(is_home() && is_front_page() || is_front_page()): // static or default hompage
 ...
endif;
```

BLOG

```
if(is_home() && !is_front_page()): // blog
 ...
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its very simple I was in a same situation and I used the following technique which is to use the page slug.

```
if( is_page('blog') ) {
echo "This is your blog page"; 
}
```

But make sure you've not selected homepage to display recent blog posts and you have set a specific page for blogs like blog or news etc, just use that page slug and you'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution instead of checking if the page is home or archive or not OR & AND you can simply check the template you use.

For example:
I use in my blog posts page this template:

```
template-blog.php
```

So, I can distinguish it from any other page as follow:

```
if( is_page_template('template-blog.php') ) {}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... Even if I go inside individual posts blog menu is activated. With this, you can always target the blog page.

[Note: This will work when if your blog is the 'Posts Page']
[image]

```
   <li <?php if(get_post_type() == 'post' )
     {echo 'class="current-menu-item"';} ?> >
       <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog');?>">
         Blog
       </a>
    </li>
```