# is_home() vs is_archive()

Tags: conditional-tags

I have set my front page set to be a static front page, "Home," and my Posts page is set to my "News" page.

When on my News page, `is_home()` returns `1` as expected but `is_archive()` returns `0`. I would expect that it would return `1` also. The WP doc for `is_archive()` doesn't make it clearer for me. It reads,

> checks if any type of Archive page is being displayed. An Archive is a Category, Tag, Author or a Date based pages.

I would expect that to be true. Something isn't connecting for me.

What is the difference between `is_home()` and `is_archive()`?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I forgot to come back here after I got it working. I'll close it now.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly understand the difference, you have to dig into the Wordpress Core

- [`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) (defined in [wp-includes/query.php#L140](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L140)) checks any type of archive page. These archive pages is defined in the `WP_Query` class in [wp-includes/query.php#L1615](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1615) lines 1615 and line 1616

  ```
  1615    if ( $this->is_post_type_archive || $this->is_date || $this->is_author || $this->is_category || $this->is_tag || $this->is_tax )
  1616    $this->is_archive = true;
  ```
- [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)(defined in [wp-includes/query.php#L443](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L443)) will return true when you are on the home page, which is whenever any of the conditions/pages returns false as defined in the `WP_Query` class in [wp-includes/query.php#L1648](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1648) lines 1648 and 1649

  ```
  1648    if ( !( $this->is_singular || $this->is_archive || $this->is_search || $this->is_feed || $this->is_trackback || $this->is_404 || $this->is_admin || $this->is_comments_popup || $this->is_robots ) )
  1649    $this->is_home = true;
  ```

As for your question, whenever a static front page is set, Wordpress uses front-page.php, page.php or any other custom page template. The proper conditional to use here is [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

For the page set as the blog page, Wordpress uses home.php or index.php. This is your actual homepage of your blog, and not an archive page. `is_home()` will return true and `is_archive()` will return false as expected

For futher reading:

- [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)
- [Creating a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)
- [Query Overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)

Comment: See also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107141/check-if-current-page-is-the-blog-page

Answer (score 2):

if you have home.php/index.php on your theme it's your first page and function is_home() return true in this page.

but when you are on archive.php function is_archive() will return true.
archive.php is for displaying posts of a year or a month or a day.
you can test archive functionality with adding it's widget to your site.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @AmirMasoud's answer, when you're on your news feed, it is not actually displaying a category, tag, author, etc specific set of posts.

Also in your options there is a place you can define home. That page may be outside of using index.php and will be the only page that returns 1 as `is_home()`.

Archive can be set a lot of different ways. Look up the template hierarchy to better understand home, archive and the other page file options.

Comment: "Archive can be set a lot of different ways" Please explain what you mean. You cannot set an archive page

Comment: Well that is a good question... it isn't really the developer setting them that was more of a wording mistake. But there are defaults that are set. So archives are set for multiple ways. But you can set a variety of php files that all act as archives. Not just archive.php.

Comment: You can create the following archive pages, archive.php, category.php, taxonomy.php, tag.php, author.php and date.php and any of their hierarchial pages according to the template hierarchy ;-)

Comment: Exactly! :D Your answer is much more in depth. I wanted to go a little bit more, but was on my phone so I'm very glad you were able to do that!